# Bootstrap Modal Plugin is not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-modal

i am using bootstrap modal i want to list employee details on my pop but thats not working properly.

index.html.erb

```
     <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-<%= current_user.id %>"> 
                                 <%= image_tag("view.png",:size=>"30x30") %></a></td>
                                 </tr>
                                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-<%= current_user.id %>" role="dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                      <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                              <div class="modal-body">        
                <strong>RollID:</strong>
                <%= current_user.roll_id %>
            </div>
```

application.html.erb

```
<title>EmployeeManagementSystem</title>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Material+Icons" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.min.js"%>
   <%= yield %>
```

application.js

```
//= require activestorage
//= require jquery.validate
//= require jquery.validate.additional-methods
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
//= require_tree .
```

gem file https://imgur.com/a/RxWpe8v
please tell any mistake in my code.have another way to implement modal tel me.
Thanks Advance

Comment: What does it mean that it doesn't work properly? What happens?

Comment: Did you bootstrap.js in your app ?

Comment: Hi Divya, without knowing what is expected, its very difficult to tell you what the problem is and fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include bootstrap components or bootstrap-sprockets.js to your app/assets/javascripts/application.js file. As bootstrap depends on jquery i'd put after jquery.

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```